# Azure network configuration to connect vm and docker container

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to build a cloud setup on Azure where a database is running inside a virtual machine and a docker container needs to connect to the database.

My setup so far:

```
$resourceGroup="my-rg" 
$registryName="mycontainerregistry"
$image="mydockerimage"
$containerName="test-container"
$servicePrincipalPull="sp-container-registry-pull"
$servicePrincipalPush="sp-container-registry-push"
$dnsNameLabel="mydockerimage"
$vnetName="vmVNET"
$vnetVmSubnet="vmSubnet"
$vnetNameContainer="containerVNET"
$vnetSubnetContainer="containerSubnet"
$vmIp="10.0.0.4"
$privateNet="10.0.0.0"
$privateNetContainer="10.0.1.0"
$vmDataDisk="oradata01"
$vmmName="MyVirtualMachine"
$netSecurityGroup="myNSG"
$vmSize="Standard_DS2_v2"
$whiteListIPAddresses="my public IPs"

$loginServer="$registryName.azurecr.io"
$imageTag="$loginServer/$image`:v1"

# login to Azure
az login

az group create --name $resourceGroup --location northeurope

az network vnet create --name $vnetName --resource-group $resourceGroup --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet-name $vnetVmSubnet --subnet-prefixes 10.0.0.0/24

az vm create --name $vmName --resource-group $resourceGroup --image Oracle:oracle-database-19-3:oracle-database-19-0904:latest --size $vmSize --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys --private-ip-address $vmIp --public-ip-address-allocation static --public-ip-address-dns-name $vmName --vnet $vnetName --vnet-address-prefix $privateNet/16 --subnet $vnetVmSubnet --subnet-address-prefix  $privateNet/24

az vm disk attach --name $vmDataDisk --new --resource-group $resourceGroup --size-gb 64 --sku StandardSSD_LRS --vm-name $vmName

az network nsg create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $netSecurityGroup

az network nsg rule create --resource-group $resourceGroup --nsg-name $netSecurityGroup --name allow-oracle --protocol tcp --priority 1001 --destination-port-range 1521 --source-address-prefixes $whiteListIPAddresses

az network nsg rule create --resource-group $resourceGroup --nsg-name $netSecurityGroup --name allow-oracle-EM --protocol tcp --priority 1002 --destination-port-range 5502 --source-address-prefixes $whiteListIPAddresses

az network nsg rule create --resource-group $resourceGroup --nsg-name $netSecurityGroup --name allow-SSH --protocol tcp --priority 1003 --destination-port-range 22 --source-address-prefixes $whiteListIPAddresses

$publicIP=(az network public-ip show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name vmoracle19cPublicIP --query "ipAddress" --output tsv)

Write-Host "Access $vmName on public address $publicIP"   

# create container registry
az acr create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $registryName --sku Basic

# get the container registry resource identifyer
$resourceID=(az acr show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $registryName --query id --output tsv)

# Create the service principal with rights scoped to the registry.
# Default permissions are for docker pull access. Modify the '--role'
# argument value as desired:
# acrpull:     pull only
# acrpush:     push and pull
# owner:       push, pull, and assign roles
$spPushPassword=(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $servicePrincipalPush --scopes $resourceID --role acrpush --query "password" --output tsv)
$spPushUserName=(az ad sp list --display-name $servicePrincipalPush --query "[].appId" --output tsv)

# login to Azure container registry
az acr login --name $registryName --username $spPushUserName --password $spPushPassword

# tag the local image
docker tag $image $imageTag

# push the image to Azure container registry
docker push $imageTag

# list the container registry contents, just for show
az acr repository list --name $registryName --output table

# Create the service principal with rights scoped to the registry.
# Default permissions are for docker pull access. Modify the '--role'
# argument value as desired:
# acrpull:     pull only
# acrpush:     push and pull
# owner:       push, pull, and assign roles
$spPullPassword=$(az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $servicePrincipalPull --scopes $resourceID --role acrpull --query "password" --output tsv)
$spPullUserName=$(az ad sp list --display-name $servicePrincipalPull --query "[].appId" --output tsv)

az network vnet subnet create --resource-group $resourceGroup --vnet-name $vnetName --name $vnetSubnetContainer --address-prefixes $privateNetContainer/24 --network-security-group $netSecurityGroup

az network vnet create --name $vnetNameContainer --resource-group $resourceGroup --address-prefix $privateNet/16 --subnet-name $vnetSubnetContainer --subnet-prefixes $privateNetContainer/24

az container create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name importcontainer --image $imageTag --registry-login-server $loginServer --registry-username $spPullUserName --registry-password $spPullPassword --ip-address Private --vnet $vnetNameContainer --vnet-address-prefix $privateNet/16 --subnet $vnetSubnetContainer --subnet-address-prefix  $privateNetContainer/24
```

I thought I could reuse the same VNET for both the VM and the container, but that gives an error in lines of "(SubnetDelegationsCannotChangeWhenSubnetUsedByResource) Delegations of subnet .... cannot be changed from [] to [Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups] because it is being used by the resource ...VMNic/ipConfigurations/ipconfigvm

So I went ahead and created a separate VNET in the same 10.0.0.0/16 scope but with the 10.0.1.0/24 subnet.

It seems as if the container is unable to reach the database inside the VM.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your case, you're trying to use the same subnet for both the VM and the container, and Azure doesn't allow you to change the subnet delegation once it's in use. you should create separate VNETs and subnets for the VM and the container, which you've already done. But you need to create a new subnet for your container instance. Try to allow incoming traffic on port 1521 and port 22.

Comment: Orelse, you can connect virtual networks to each other with virtual network peering check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-connect-virtual-networks-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why this didn't work in the first place, but I found a working solution.

Now I create the VNET and container subnet before assigning it to a VM

```
# login to Azure
az login

# Create the resource group
az group create --name $resourceGroup --location $region

# Create network security group to be used for VNET
az network nsg create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $netSecurityGroup

# Create VNET
az network vnet create --name $vnetName --resource-group $resourceGroup --address-prefix $privateNet/16 --subnet-name $vnetVmSubnet --subnet-prefixes $privateNet/24 --network-security-group $netSecurityGroup

# Add container subnet to VNET
az network vnet subnet create --resource-group $resourceGroup --vnet-name $vnetName --name $vnetContainerSubnet --address-prefixes $privateNetContainer/24 --network-security-group $netSecurityGroup

# Create VM to host Oracle database
az vm create --name $oracleVmName --resource-group $resourceGroup --image Oracle:oracle-database-19-3:oracle-database-19-0904:latest --size $vmSize --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys --private-ip-address $oracleIp --public-ip-address-allocation static --public-ip-address-dns-name $oracleVmName --vnet-name $vnetName --subnet $vnetVmSubnet # --vnet-address-prefix $privateNet/16 --subnet-address-prefix  $privateNet/24

... setup network security etc

# Create the container
az container create --resource-group $resourceGroup --name importcontainer --image $imageTag --registry-login-server $loginServer --registry-username $spPullUserName --registry-password $spPullPassword --ip-address Private --vnet $vnetName --subnet $vnetContainerSubnet
```

Now I am able to access the database from a running container as I intended.